# Columns get lost on pandas frame join

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets:

1. Dataset **A** represents the number of fans a player of a team has in a specific year
2. Dataset **B** represents the number of wins a team has in a specific game

I would now like to combine both data frames and aggregate the data per year per team.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996],
    'team': ['Panthers', 'Panthers', 'Eagles', 'Eagles', 'Panthers', 'Panthers', 'Eagles', 'Eagles'],
    'name': ['Joe', 'Betty', 'James', 'Sandra', 'Tyrone', 'Betty', 'James', 'Michael'],
    'fans': [100, 200, 244, 277, 800, 900, 122, 300]
})

b = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996],
    'team': ['Panthers', 'Panthers', 'Eagles', 'Eagles', 'Panthers', 'Panthers', 'Eagles', 'Eagles'],
    'wins': [4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 4]
})

aa = a.groupby(['year', 'team']).sum()
bb = b.groupby(['year', 'team']).sum()

aa.join(bb)
```

This works but there seems to be some problem with the columns. The final operation `aa.join(bb).columns` only yields into `['fans', 'wins']`. I guess this is a left over from an incomplete `groupby` operation.

To give you a better insight you can view the data with nbviewer [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/bodokaiser/fad68c0965fc6e563434/raw/8fc86dcc40e34406d3b1be45200c84fbdb7d39a8/join.ipynb).

**How do I properly do a group-by and join these two frames?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** `reset_index()` can be used only once.

```
aa = a.groupby(['year', 'team']).sum()
bb = b.groupby(['year', 'team']).sum()

aa.join(bb).reset_index()
```

**2)** Alternatively, don't create levels for `aa` and `bb` using `as_index=False` and `pd.merge`

```
aa = a.groupby(['year', 'team'], as_index=False).sum()
bb = b.groupby(['year', 'team'], as_index=False).sum()

pd.merge(aa, bb)
```

Both methods, will give you same output

```
    year    team        fans    wins
0   1995    Eagles       521    8
1   1995    Panthers     300    6
2   1996    Eagles       422    6
3   1996    Panthers    1700    13
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to apply `reset_index()` to "end" the group-by operation.

So following will yield in the correct result:

```
aa = a.groupby(['year', 'team']).sum().reset_index()
bb = b.groupby(['year', 'team']).sum().reset_index()

pd.merge(aa, bb)
```